# How to access a remote database from Jquery Mobile application?

Tags: jquery, mobile, remote-access

I am in the process of developing a JQuery Mobile application for my college. I will need to access the database of my university in my application. I read some tutorials on JQuery Mobile. All of them are UI based. I want to know if there is a way to access the remote database? Please provide your suggestions or any useful links you know of

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'd proxy it or store a cache of the database and make it available as a web service that gives you restful JSON for the items in the database. If your app will be on another domain, also provide it as JSONP.

Then use [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) to represent each of the tables/resources that you need as Backbone Models.

I've done a couple of JQuery Mobile sites like this. Here's one where I took an API to 1m cultural artefacts in the UK and made them available for mobile:

Try it: http://culturegridapp.heroku.com

Source code: https://github.com/stefl/Culturegridmobile