# Database record wont show on my mobile application

Tags: php, android, html, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I use html5 + css3 + jquery mobile to built my mobile application. Actually I've already desktop version, and i want to make mobile application.

1. Is that true php wont work on html5 for mobile application?
2. If that true, i use ajax for call my JSON (that place create on jsontext.php).
3. I tried HTML5 on desktop browser and it worked.
4. I built it to apk using build.phonegap.com and install the apk to my device.
5. After that, my database record not showing. Maybe it didn't execute.

Other user in stackoverflow said we can use backbone.js. [how-to-access-a-remote-database-from-jquery-mobile-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825003/how-to-access-a-remote-database-from-jquery-mobile-application)

are my steps right? or I have to use backbone.js. THX.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some answers:

1. Yes, php won't work in a mobile native/hibrid mobile application,
   because php needs to be interpreted by a php server before
   generating output.
2. Its easy and simple to both generate and parse JSON, it's widely
   used in apps.
3. That is good. If you want an 'online-only' kind of app, you can use
   a webview and point it the url of your app - its basically a browser
   without navigation buttons and user interface - but something's
   don't work that well, you should test before. It may also display
   your app as sluggish and unpolished.
4. No problem with that, Cordova/Phonegap is actually becoming a very
   good mobile framework. You should also install ADB
   (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html), ADT
   (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html) and the Android
   device emulator
   (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html).
5. You must be sure on how to insert and retrieve dabatase records.
   This depends on how you programmed it. Be sure to have the database
   available publicly (accessible only from the apps, though).

Hope I've answered your questions, and that it helped.